# Is there a way to access/read and modify the contents of .swz files?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop

There's a 2D party fighter game I play (which runs on Adobe AIR and uses As3==S3) that stores all the instruction code in a .swf that is ran when the game is booted up. When the game is booted up, a method called init() is run that loads all the necessary files for the game, which are comprised of swf's and a couple .swz's. There is a file called init.swz which presumably holds all the variables for the game that I desire to document and edit, however I do not know how to open it and edit it.

After searching for the swz file extension online, I've tried opening it in the programs more websites suggest (adobe flash, flash builder, and adobe flex) but none seem to open the file. I did figure out that the game does uncompress the file before reading it presumably as a ByteArray. I opened the game in a hex editor through reading RAM and it displayed the contents in a format that reminds me of XML.

```java
var _loc11_:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
         var _loc12_:uint = int(_loc2_.readInt());
         var _loc13_:uint = int(_loc2_.readInt());
         _loc11_.length = _loc12_;
         _loc8_ = 0;
         _loc9_ = int(_loc12_);
         while(_loc8_ < _loc9_)
         {
            _loc8_++;
            _loc10_ = _loc8_;
            _loc14_ = _loc10_ & 7;
            _loc15_ = uint(_loc2_.readUnsignedByte());
            _loc11_[_loc10_] = _loc15_ ^ _loc4_ & 255;
            _loc4_ = uint(_loc4_ << uint(32 - _loc14_)) | uint(_loc4_ >>> _loc14_);
         }
         _loc11_.uncompress();
```

Given the above information, is there anyway to be able to access it in a **readable format** and modify some of it's contents? (Sorry for bad formatting, I'm new to stackoverflow post-wise)